# SQL query taking 35 mins

Tags: sql, query-performance

How can I improve the performance of the below query? It currently takes 35 minutes.

```
-- Select    
SELECT   
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.FECDATA,  RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.L2V,  
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.CODCONT, SUM(RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IMPMOCMP) 
FROM  
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS,
    RPT_FT_MC_CONTR     
WHERE    
    -- joins
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDGRUEMP = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.IDGRUEMP AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.FECDATA  = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.FECDATA AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.CODCONT  = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.CODCONT AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDEMPR   = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.IDEMPR AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDCENT   = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.IDCENT AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.CODPROD  = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.CODPROD AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDCONTR  = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.IDCONTR AND 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDSCONTR = RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.IDSCONTR AND
    -- filters
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.FECDATA  = '31-May-2014' AND
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDGRUEMP = '0022' AND
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.ACUMTEMP = 'MTH' AND  
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.IDESCENA = '01' AND
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.CODCONT='CCPP' 
--group by 
GROUP BY 
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.FECDATA,
    RPT_FT_MC_CONTR.L2V,
    RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS.CODCONT
```

- `RPT_FT_MC_CONTR` :  39 million rows
- `RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS` : 145 million rows

Here is the result of the explain command:

Explain Command

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2459895390

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                 |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR                 |                 |       |       |            |          |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)           | :TQ10002        |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |  Q1,02 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                |                 |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   4 |     PX RECEIVE                  |                 |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX SEND HASH               | :TQ10001        |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY             |                 |   268 | 29212 | 30846   (8)| 00:09:16 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                |                 |    39M|  4127M| 30586   (7)| 00:09:11 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR       |                 |    39M|  1893M| 10659   (4)| 00:03:12 |     1 |    16 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | RPT_FT_MC_CONTR |    39M|  1893M| 10659   (4)| 00:03:12 |   833 |   848 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |         PX RECEIVE              |                 |   145M|  8184M| 19806   (9)| 00:05:57 |       |       |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |          PX SEND BROADCAST LOCAL| :TQ10000        |   145M|  8184M| 19806   (9)| 00:05:57 |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->P | BCST LOCAL |
|  12 |           PX BLOCK ITERATOR     |                 |   145M|  8184M| 19806   (9)| 00:05:57 |    66 |    66 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|* 13 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL    | RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS |   145M|  8184M| 19806   (9)| 00:05:57 |    66 |    66 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."CODCONT"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."CODCONT" AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."FECDATA"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."FECDATA" AND
              "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDGRUEMP"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDGRUEMP" AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDEMPR"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDEMPR" AND
              "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDCENT"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDCENT" AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."CODPROD"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."CODPROD" AND
              "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDCONTR"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDCONTR" AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDSCONTR"="RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDSCONTR")
   9 - filter("RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."IDGRUEMP"='0022' AND "RPT_FT_MC_CONTR"."FECDATA"=TO_DATE(' 2014-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss'))
  13 - filter("RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDESCENA"='01' AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."FECDATA"=TO_DATE(' 2014-05-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd
              hh24:mi:ss') AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."IDGRUEMP"='0022' AND "RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS"."ACUMTEMP"='MTH')
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for editing, it now looks clear

Comment: Your join syntax is [ancient](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and you **NEED** to fix it.

Comment: Why do you need to join 2 tables on so many criteria?

Comment: This is a business reporting requirement

Comment: @nkalis if it's only two tables you only need to join on the items that bring the table together. Once the table is joined you don't need to add more predicates. Is there some sort of ID that they have in common? Also do you have any indexes as it appears none are being used.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright for some reason or another I'm going to try to help with this query. So lets start by cleaning it up so that it can be used. First off we will start by obliterating the [ancient join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). We will also add some aliases. Aliasing is when you give a title a nickname that you can then reference all over the place that way we don't clutter the code with repeated table names everywhere. That gives us something like this.

```
SELECT   
    F.FECDATA,  
    C.L2V,  
    F.CODCONT, 
    SUM(F.IMPMOCMP) 
FROM RPT_FT_MD_FLOWS as F
INNER JOIN RPT_FT_MC_CONTR as C
    ON F.IDGRUEMP = C.IDGRUEMP  
    AND F.FECDATA  = C.FECDATA  
    AND F.CODCONT  = C.CODCONT  
    AND F.IDEMPR   = C.IDEMPR  
    AND F.IDCENT   = C.IDCENT  
    AND F.CODPROD  = C.CODPROD  
    AND F.IDCONTR  = C.IDCONTR  
    AND F.IDSCONTR = C.IDSCONTR 
WHERE F.FECDATA  = '31-May-2014' 
    AND F.IDGRUEMP = '0022' 
    AND F.ACUMTEMP = 'MTH'   
    AND F.IDESCENA = '01' 
    AND F.CODCONT='CCPP' 
GROUP BY 
    F.FECDATA,
    C.L2V,
    F.CODCONT
```

So lets start with these join predicates. I know you claim these are business rules but is this all really necessary to join two tables together? If it is than your table structure is boned. There should be zero reason to have 9 join predicates to bring 2 tables together. Are they all truly increasing the selectivity of the query? If this is all truly required then your table structure needs to be fixed.

Next your table doesn't seem to be taking advantage of any indexes. If you don't have this already you should have some sort of clustered index on these tables to ease searching.

You probably also want to add some other indexes to this table as well to help with reducing the many the amount of data it has to scan/seek through to get your results. There is no reason that your query should have to join all 184 million rows to return 268 rows.

Comment: The real solution here is to fix the design of the tables. There shouldn't be a need to make a join on 8 columns.

Comment: @Kermit I highly doubt that there is even now.

Comment: Hi Kermit, Could you please xplain me more on this - The real solution here is to fix the design of the tables, i would put this across solution

Comment: I don't think that's a topic that can simply be addressed in an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rewrite your query from start

1. Use normal joins (INNER) between tables and only include a where clause with filters applied that are not joins.
2. Look at how well normalised the database is, if it is well normalised you should be able to optimise your indexes and statistics to improve query performance.
3. Look at things like partitioning that could come in handy.
4. Check how fragmented the data pages are and fix that if that's causing a problem.